# cannot drag and drop widgets since wordpress 3.2.1

Tags: widgets, jquery

I recently updated my site to wordpress 3.2.1 automatically.

Now I tried to manage my sidebar widgets, and noticed I can no longer drag and drop the widgets around. If I look into my browser-console, I notice that the page is unable to load jQuery. Weird: it appends my root-url to the jquery-url, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://meanderend.dixis.com//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2.1"></script>
```

So it is normal that it is not found. How can I 
fix this. Is there something wrong in my configuration? Or is this a bug? Then it should be general, for everybody, no?

Comment: WordPress doesn't normally load jQuery from Google's CDN, I'd guess you have a plugin or theme interfering here.

Comment: In my admin section? Oh wait, a plugin might be possible maybe. I will investigate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your theme may be written badly and replace the correct jQuery. Switch to TwentyEleven to check for this. If this doesn’t help, turn off all plugins and re-enable them step by step.

Comment: Amazing. I first deactivated all plugins, without any result. Then I switched the theme back to TwentyEleven, and everything works just fine. Thank you! I would have assumed a theme could not interfere with the admin section ... But of course it could add an extra page there as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, themes can do most of the things a plugin can do too. Many developers don’t get the difference and put a lot of pure plugin logic into their theme.

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of this problem (still occurs in 3.3.1 by the way...) is a plugin conflict. We have seen this behavior with both the White Label CMS plugin as well as a combination of Event Espresso and Easy Toolbox.

A couple suggestions have resolved for some ...

1. place "define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);"  in the wp-config.php file
2. reset the plugins folder  (logout, rename plugins folder to "plugins.hold", log back in and then change the folder name back to plugins)

However, neither of those are a sure bet -- just less painful than the common plugin conflict issue.  Two approaches to tracking down the conflict ... disable one at a time and check the widgets, or disable them all and turn back on one at a time. Either way, helps to have a pair of browsers or at least a pair of browsers tabs in play to minimize the needed clicks.